# Python in AWS Lambda: "module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, python-requests

I'm currently trying to use the Python `requests` module in an AWS Lambda function. Here are the steps that I've taken so far:

I created a new directory, and installed the requests module in it, using the command `pip3 install requests -t .`

I then wrote a simple Python script, `test_requests.py`, within the directory, which looks like this:

```
import requests
def my_handler(event, context):
    r = requests.get("http://google.com")
    return r
```

I zipped the entire directory, including the requests module, using `zip test_requests.zip *`

I then uploaded the function to AWS with the following command: `aws lambda create-function --function-name test_requests --zip-file fileb://test_requests.zip --handler test_requests.my_handler --runtime python3.6 --region us-east-1 --role xxxMY_ROLE_ARNxxx`

Finally, I invoked the function with this command: `aws lambda invoke --function-name test-requests --payload {} --region us-east-1 lambda_response.txt`

When I made this command, I got an unhandled exception back from Lambda. The output file, `lambda_response.txt` contained this: `{"errorMessage": "module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'", "errorType": "AttributeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/test_requests.py", 3, "my_handler", "r = requests.get('http://google.com')"]]}`

I've seen several questions regarding AWS lambda, and being unable to import modules properly. Those questions all seemed focused around lambda being unable to find the module. In this case, it seems that lambda has found requests, but is unable to access all of its attributes.

Comment: Check the version of python, you are trying to run the script

Comment: @bigbounty `pip3 -V` returns `pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: Why did you zip `requests` module? Doesn't it come with Python distribution in Lambda?

Comment: Why not download the requests by git clone, then zip it and upload to AWS and install it by `python setup.py install`

Comment: I have just tested your exact process (except I'm using python 2.7), and ... it's working. I think you may have a bad `requests.py` or `requests.pyc` file in your directory that is shadowing the real `requests` module.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. `zip test.zip *` only zips the top level of the directory structure. I needed the `-r` flag in order to capture everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for documenting it! I was going to spend the whole day trying find a solution related to anything other than that!